# Apply style on parent when hovering over a specific child element using tailwind

Tags: tailwind-css

I have something like this:

```html
<main id="parent" class="h-screen flex justify-center items-center">
  
  <div id="child" class="bg-red-200 w-96 h-72 flex">
  </div>
  
</main>
```

How would I go about applying `.bg-blue-100` to the `#parent` only when hovering over `#child`?

(I understand that the opposite could be achieved using `group` on the parent, and `group-hover` on the child.)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can give the parent `pointer-events-none` and the child `pointer-events-auto` then apply `hover:bg-100` or whatever hover effect to the parent and it should only trigger when the child is hovered. Here's an example on Tailwind Play https://play.tailwindcss.com/W4C3J3tW6E

```
<main id="parent" class="h-screen flex justify-center items-center
hover:bg-blue-100 pointer-events-none">
  <div id="child" class="bg-red-200 w-96 h-72 flex pointer-events-auto">
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Awesome way to hack it.
In the other hand it does not seem to work with focus: classes if the parent can't be focused

(Use case: style parent when the child is focused)

Comment: @LoïcV for that you can use `focus-within` on the parent and add a tabindex to the child so it can be focused. https://play.tailwindcss.com/ujBKWsj3Yo

Comment: @LoïcV saw your answer after commenting, yes that lol.

Answer (score 14):

In case you also want to style the parent whenever the child is focused, just add

```
"focus-within:bg-indigo-500"
```

(Obviously replacing "bg-indigo-500" by your style)

This would work when it happens for every child or if you only have one tho.

Comment: Can you give some explanation please as to who should get this class? The parent or the child? What does it actually do? How does it work?

Answer (score 0):

With the latest tailwind, you can achieve this with unique group names: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#differentiating-nested-groups

If there are multiple iterations with the unique group name, only the currently hovered group will be affected.

```
<tr 
     v-for="song of songs"
     :key="song.id"
     class="group/row"
>
    <td class="group-hover/row:bg-zinc-900">{{ song.name }}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: This apply the style on the child when hovering over the parent element. It does not answer the question, but still awesome though.